# jQuery autocomplete has stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I've a pretty long sign up form and I have autocomplete on one field which has worked before. The site is on WordPress, I've loaded jQuery UI in main.js and it is shown on the source of the page. And it's included after jQuery. Here's the snippet that powers the autocomplete.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {var kurssit = [<?php echo file_get_contents("http://xxx.xxx", "r");?>];
$("#kurssi").autocomplete({
source: kurssit
});
});
```

And php will load it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {var kurssit = [
"Taaperokurssi",
"Junnukurssi",
"Yhteiseloa myötäkarvaan",
"Lapsi ja koira",
"Pentutoko",
"Aktivoi tokolla",
"Rallytoko",
"Näyttelyyn tutustumiskurssi",
"Ratkaisuja pulmalliseen ohitukseen",
"Ratkaisuja pulmalliseen ohitukseen - jatkokurssi",
"Hihna-, kontakti- ja luoksetulokurssi",
"Naksutin",
"Lupa koskea",
"Sienikurssi",
"Mejä",
"Mejä jatkokurssi",
"Puuhakurssi",
"Koiranhoidon ABC",
"Hieronta",];
    $("#kurssi").autocomplete({
    source: kurssit
    });
});
```

It should work, why it won't work?

Comment: "won't work" is no error msg. have you checked firebug?

Comment: Can you please post your code on jsfiddle ? Moreover, you've an extra comma at the end of your array

Comment: The extra comma shouldn't break it, it's easier for my customer to update the code if he just copy pastes and edits the code.

Comment: Should be nothing wrong with your code, try recreate the error in jsfiddle or debug it in your own js debugger. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source is correct usage

Comment: @jtheman I **hate** firefox as it's unsecure, but here's what I found in Chrome's console : `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' [http://new.hurttiajahuumoria.fi/ilmoittaudu:276]`

Comment: are you sure jquery ui is loaded correct with autocomplete function?

Comment: In modern browser, it should not. But in IE6, it will break because of the comma.

Comment: @jtheman as it worked before, and I've included the whole jquery-ui.min.js so it should be.

Comment: @itachi I've totally dropped support for IE6. And it worked in IE7.

Comment: let IE6 rest in it's well deserved grave!!!

Comment: Funny, that a site I've made before isn't working properly in IE6 but it's working perfectly on IE5.

Comment: Is loading (1st jquery, then autocomplete, then the call) sequence are in correct order? From the error, it seems like it isn't. Plus, did you recently added any other jquery plugins-

Comment: @itachi no, I haven't added any plugins. Autocomplete call is loaded last, so it should work.

Comment: I replicate your problem on JSfiddle and the error Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' only occurs when the Jquery UI library is not loaded. If you add a head: <head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head> it starts working as you expect. Try using Chrome and see if the library is loaded correctly inspecting the "Network" option.

Comment: Before diving into codes, i'l check few pretty basic things. 1st, check all the files are loaded or not. Showing on source page isn't enough. Click the source link and see if you get object not found error. 2nd, check jquery is loaded or not if its loading from your server and not from google or others.

Comment: you have two element with same id  `id="kurssi"`

Comment: @chumkiu that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have two element with the same id

```
id="kurssi"
```